# Dirty page accounting in linux kernel /proc/$PID/maps

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

TLDR;
How exactly does the kernel is able to do dirty page accounting in `/proc/$PID/maps`.

Consider the following program statement in C

```c
static char page1[PAGE_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (PAGE_SIZE)))
```

Now uninitialized variables are zero at start. My understanding is that on the start of the program, the kernel maps uninitilized variables to zero page, and does copy-on-write lazy allocation of the page. Fine make sense, and that way kernel can account for dirty page of the uninitialized sections when page fault occurs.

Now consider the statement

```c
static char page1[PAGE_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (PAGE_SIZE))) = {'c'}
```

Here, the loader will load the values for page1 at init of the program, and
mark the page as RW. So any write done by the program must be invisible to kernel
as no page fault is triggered.

Here is the program I wrote for experimentation.

```c
#define PAGE_SIZE (4*1024)
static char page1[PAGE_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (PAGE_SIZE))) = {'c'};
int main()
{
  char c; int i; int *d;
  scanf("%c", &c);                // --------- tag 1
  for(i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++)
    {
      page1[i] = c;               // --------- tag 2
    }
  d = malloc(sizeof(int));
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Now before and after tag 1 (comments in code), the output of `/proc/$PID/smaps` for
the section containing `page1` is pasted below in table

| smap | BEFORE TAG-1 | AFTER TAG-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Size: | 8 kB | 8 kB |
| KernelPageSize: | 4 kB | 4 kB |
| MMUPageSize: | 4 kB | 4 kB |
| Rss: | 8 kB | 8 kB |
| Pss: | 8 kB | 8 kB |
| Shared_Clean: | 0 kB | 0 kB |
| Shared_Dirty: | 0 kB | 0 kB |
| **Private_Clean**: | 4 kB | 0 kB |
| **Private_Dirty**: | 4 kB | 8 kB |
| Referenced: | 8 kB | 8 kB |
| **Anonymous**: | 4 kB | 8 kB |

As you can see, the bold coloured parameters changed.

Questions

1. How on earth did kernel got to know i wrote the page?
2. What is this anonymous field and why it changed?

Any other page/blog/manual explaining all the working in detailed
will be helpful.

My guess:

Maybe the kernel marks the page as RO, even though it is RW so that page
fault triggers and it can do the accouting. Or maybe there is some other process
that continuously walks the page tables of processes, but that is just too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

1. On most (perhaps all, I haven’t checked) architectures supported by Linux, the MMU keeps track of which pages are dirty. So the kernel can clear the dirty bit in the page table entry when the page is initialised, even with non-zero content, and the MMU will update it when the page is modified.
2. Anonymous memory is memory which isn’t file-backed. By writing to your page, you’ve increased the amount of memory which isn’t file-backed — on initialisation, it was backed by the executable image, but once changed it no longer is.

To see where the kernel checks for dirty pages, look [for references to `pte_dirty`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/pte_dirty).

The kernel also maintains [a “soft-dirty” bit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/soft-dirty.html), which can be cleared from userspace and is used by checkpoint-restore.

Comment: IBM's POWER architecture did change the view - the hardware only handles translations for the number of pages the system's RAM supports. 64 M RAM -> the machine can only support 16384 virtual pages (4 kB each) -> the hardware only needs to support translation for 16384 pages,  not for 524288 pages.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund I think I’m missing something — how does that affect dirty page tracking?

Comment: That architecture (POWER) compared with for example SPARC and 386 turned the MMU upside down, previously design was based around having tables big enough to support maximum virtual memory of the architecture.  Though i don't think Linux ever ran on POWER 1.  PPC (and since POWER 5) is another thing.  My point is that the kernel had to maintain it's tables itself - the MMU doesn't tracks dirtiness on them after the page is marked up as being RW

Comment: especially for MIPS R3000.

Comment: On the MIPS R3000,  it was expected of the kernel that it was fast refilling the TLB on a refill-table trap ie reference to unknown page.